# How do I use std::sort in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting

I am using the std::sort function in `<algorithm>`. I followed the examples given at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/. I want to use the example that looks like this:

```
// using default comparison (operator <):
   std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+4);
```

Applied to my classes, it looks like this:

```
std::sort(newTuples->begin(), newTuples->end());
```

where `newTuples` is of type

```
std::vector<Tuple>*
```

So I overrode the `operator<` function of the `Tuple` class:

```
bool const Tuple::operator<(Tuple * tup1){
    bool result = false;

    for(int iii=0; iii<tup1->size(); iii++){
        if(tup1->at(iii)->getTokensValue() < this->at(iii)->getTokensValue()){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (tup1->at(iii)->getTokensValue() > this->at(iii)->getTokensValue())
            break;
    }

    return result;


}
```

The problem is that when I try to build in XCode, it gives me the error shown:

[image: Xcode error]

which code snippet is in `<algorithm>`.

It gives me a stack trace of sorts, one line of which gives me the following:

[image: xcode error 2]

which code snippet is in my `Tuple.h` file.

I don't know what else to do! any help is greatly appreciated, as my CS class project is now 3 days late because I can't figure this LAST sorting algorithm out. I already implemented a Relational Database Management System with relations and the relational operations select, project, and rename. I have these tuples correctly formatted, they just need to be in sorted order. Thanks!

EDIT:

So I changed the declarations as suggested in the answers, but now it gives me:

[image: yet another error]

Any help?

Comment: Since you have a vector of pointers, it's going to sort the pointers.

Comment: That was a typo. Originally it was a vector of pointers, so I copied it over to a new vector (hence the name newTuples) of `Tuple` and not `Tuple*`. But Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This compares a `Tuple` against a `Tuple*`

```
bool const Tuple::operator<(Tuple * tup1)
```

You should change it to this:

```
bool Tuple::operator<( const Tuple &tup1 ) const
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion. see edit above for the new error it gives me. The problem is that other functions DO use the at(int) method to modify it, so i can't just make it const...

Comment: I made the same `const` change to my `size()` function and it worked. but about that `at(int)` function?

Comment: @ejsuncy That means the functions mentioned in those errors are also not const-correct.  Make them `const`.

Comment: Can I make a function `const` even though I use it in other contexts to go in and modify whatever it returns?

Comment: @ejsuncy this site doesn't work well with conversations. I think that question would make a good new post. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You need of an operator that compares `const Tuple*` to `const Tuple*`. Inside the Tuple class declare:

```
friend bool operator<(const Tuple*, const Tuple*);
```

and implement it as a regular function.

---

**Edit**

If your vector is `std::vector<Tuple>` then you should implement:

```
bool Tuple::operator<(const Tuple&) const;
```

instead of your pointer version.

Comment: @Tushar, `const` at the end of the function definition doesn't mean anything because it's not a member function.

Comment: derp...was still looking at the member function above.